# jQuery Mobile CSS not styling JS-inserted HTML

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm making a mobile web app with Backbone.js and jQuery Mobile but I'm having some styling issues. Just to test things out I wanted to style my Logout button. Before styling, I had:

```
this.$el.append('<input type="button" id="logoutButton" value="Logout">');
```

at a certain point at my code, which had been working fine. I changed this line to:

```
this.$el.append('<a href="" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" id="logoutButton"> LOGOUT </a>');
```

But, when I do this, it just displays "LOGOUT" as a plain link with no CSS applied. I tried putting the same code in the body of my HTML file instead of inserting it with JS and it was styled correctly. I load my CSS file in the head of my document before all other files and my JS code is contained in a function bound to `$(document).ready()` so I'm not sure why the CSS is not working.

Am I missing something conceptual? How can I fix this?

Comment: can you post the css code?

Comment: @AbrahamUribe, all the CSS code I have at the moment is just the jQM CSS file, unedited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `buttonMarkup` to refresh styling like this :

```
$("#one").append('<a href="" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" id="logoutButton"> LOGOUT </a>')
$("#logoutButton").buttonMarkup("refresh");
```

Where `#one` is just a random page in HTML.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/tEnet/

[And DONT USE `ready` event with jQM.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468659/jquery-mobile-document-ready-vs-page-events)

Comment: Great, I'll try that tomorrow and see how it works. And thanks for the tip about the ready event. Wouldn't have thought of that.